# Duplicate and add same records along w/new records that have different values for one column in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have an asp.net page in C# with SQL Server and I'm trying to insert records (repeated based on the number of the records for one text field (date).

Here is the code snippets:

`aspx` page:

```
<label>First Name:</label>  <asp:TextBox runat="server" size="25" maxlength="25" ID="txtFirstName" />
<label>Last Name: </label> <asp:TextBox runat="server" size="25" maxlength="25" ID="txtLastName" />
<label>1st Date: </label> <asp:TextBox CssClass="date" ID="txtDate" runat="server" size="11" maxlength="11" />
<label>Additional Date: </label> <asp:TextBox CssClass="date" ID="txtDate2" runat="server" size="11" maxlength="11" />
<label>Additional Date: </label> <asp:TextBox CssClass="date" ID="txtDate3" runat="server" size="11" maxlength="11" />
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    string query = "INSERT INTO [myApp] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Date]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Date)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
```

What I'm trying to do is to insert FirstName, LastName text fields into FirstName and LastName database columns along with the Date text fields into the Date database column (when Submit button is clicked). I want to insert the same records (FirstName and LastName) into the database rows same as the number of dates entered by user. For example:

User enters:

```
FirstName: John
LastName: Smith
Date: 1/1/14
Additional Date: 1/2/14
Additional Date: 1/3/14
```

Database rows:

```
FirstName | LastName | Date
John        Smith      1/1/14
John        Smith      1/2/14
John        Smith      1/3/14
```

Comment: So execute the INSERT command in a loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate with code examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [myApp] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Date]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Date)";
query += "INSERT INTO [myApp] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Date]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @AdditionalDate)";
query += "INSERT INTO [myApp] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Date]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @AdditionalDate2)";
```

Just build the query with 3 inserts and add 2 more parameters `@AdditionalDate` and `@AdditionalDate2`.

Also it is good practice to wrap SqlConnection with `using`

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
}
```

so that you dispose of it always.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server (based on the syntax), you can do this in one query:

```
insert into myApp(FirstName, LastName, [date])
    select @FirstName, @LastName, thedate
    from (select @date as thedate union all
          select @additionaldate1 union all
          select @additionaldate2
         ) t;
```